# Python Create Access database using win32com

Tags: python, ms-access, win32com

I want to create an Access database (*.accdb) from within a Python script.
Using win32com and Dispatch I can call the application. However, I cant find anything on how to create a new database.

```
access = win32com.client.Dispatch('Access.Application')
```

At that point I have no need to put data into the database and I would do this using pyodbc - I simply need to create an empty database.

Does somebody has an example on how to do this?

Cheers Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an Access application object.  Use its `DBEngine.CreateDatabase` method to create your db file.

This sample worked from Python 2.7 to create an MDB format database file.  To create an ACCDB, use 128 (dbVersion120) for `dbVersion`.

```
import win32com.client
oAccess = win32com.client.Dispatch('Access.Application')
DbFile = r'C:\Users\hans\Documents\NewDb.mdb'
dbLangGeneral = ';LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0'
# dbVersion40 64
dbVersion = 64
oAccess.DBEngine.CreateDatabase(DbFile, dbLangGeneral, dbVersion)
oAccess.Quit()
del oAccess
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked like a charm!
Just one more question: Where do I gett all the information from that you set for dbLangGeneral?

Cheers Thomas

Comment: From within an Access session, I used `Debug.Print dbLangGeneral` and copied the string it returned.  See the CreateDatabase help topic for details about other options.

Answer (score 1):

To  create a new, empty .accdb file, the following Python code should do the trick:

```
import win32com.client
f = 'C:\\Users\\Gord\\Desktop\\pyTest.accdb'
c = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADOX.Catalog')
c.Create('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + f + ';')
c = None
print '"' + f + '" created.'
```

**[Edit 1]**

A comment to a blog posting [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.ca/2007/11/create-database-with-ado-ado-create.html) suggests that if the `.Create` call generates a "Class not registered" error you may need to use `regsvr32.exe` to re-register `msadox.dll`. Be aware of "bitness" when you attempt this: There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of *both* of those files:

**64-bit**
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe
C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msadox.dll

**32-bit**
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msadox.dll

Also, be aware that you could be running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit machine.

**[Edit 2]**

I've done a few tests and have reached the conclusion that this approach did not work in this particular case because the Python script was running as 64-bit, but the 64-bit Access Database Engine was not installed. (32-bit Office only installs the 32-bit version of ACE.)

The error message was perhaps a bit misleading. It wasn't the ADOX component that was missing (not registered), it was the 64-bit version of the ACE engine itself that couldn't be found.

Furthermore, on a 64-bit machine with 32-bit Access installed, the 64-bit version of ACE will *never* be available because it cannot be installed

[image: no 64-bit ACE with 32-bit Office]

This could very well have implications when you try to manipulate data within the .accdb file from a 64-bit Python script. I didn't have Python available on my "32-bit Office on 64-bit Windows" test machine, but when I tried the following VBScript...

```
Option Explicit
Dim con, rst
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\adoTest.accdb;"
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT Field1 FROM Table1", con
Wscript.Echo rst(0).Value
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

...the results were as follows:

```
C:\__tmp>C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe /nologo dataAccessTest.vbs
C:\__tmp\dataAccessTest.vbs(4, 1) ADODB.Connection: Provider cannot be found. 
It may not be properly installed.

C:\__tmp>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe /nologo dataAccessTest.vbs
This is Table1 data in Access.
```

The script failed when run as 64-bit, but it worked when run as 32-bit.

Recommendation: If your machine has 32-bit Access installed you'll probably be better off running your Python scripts as 32-bit too.

Comment: Hi Gord, thanks for the fast reply! Unfortunately it doesn't do the trick yet. I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\THOB\workspace\Toolbox\src\whales.py", line 102, in <module>
access.Create('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + fpDB + ';')
File "<COMObject ADOX.Catalog>", line 2, in Create
File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 282, in _ApplyTypes_
result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)

Comment: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, u'Class not registered', None, 0, -2147221164), None)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm absolutely sure that I'm running the 64-bit version.
I think I will try with the 32-bit version of msadox.dll since MS Office is 32-bit. Hope that will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm absolutely sure that I'm running the 64-bit version.

I tried both possibilities and unfortunately it doesn't change the error message.

Comment: @ThomasBecker Sorry, but I don't have any more ideas except to try the method suggested by HansUp in the other answer. FWIW, I did test the ADOX solution before I posted my answer and it worked for me (32-bit Python on 64-bit Vista with 64-bit Office installed).

Comment: Thanks again, and the way HansUp suggested works very well. I'm using a a 64-bit Python 27 on 64-bit Win7 but the office version installed is 32-bit...

Comment: @ThomasBecker Answer updated. You may be interested in the last bit re: data access.

Comment: @HansUp Heh, yeah. And change just one character in "bit-ness" and you've got "bit-mess", which seems somewhat appropriate, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
ConFileName = r'c:\mydb\myaccess.mdb'
try:
    Catalog = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADOX.Catalog')
    Catalog.Create('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + ConFileName + ';')
    Catalog = None
except:
    Exception as e:
        print("Database generation failed, Error="+str(e))
print("NewAccessDB.mdb created successfully")
```

Then you can connect to access database :

```
ConFileName=(r'c:\mydb\myaccess.mdb')
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + ConFileName + ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

To insert in to the access table :

```
ConFileName=(r'c:\mydb\myaccess.mdb')
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' +ConFileName+ ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for ta in TableArray:
    Sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO Table1(ID, Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6) " \
                         "VALUES ('{a}','{b}','{c}','{d}','{e}','{f}','{g}')".format(a=str(ta[0]),b=str(ta[1]),c=str(ta[2]),d=str(ta[3]),e=str(ta[4]),f=str(ta[5]),g=str(ta[6]))
    cursor.execute(Sql_insert_query)
    conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Please follow this link for more information :

https://elvand.com/python-and-ms-access/