# Python comtypes with MS Access

Tags: python, ms-access, comtypes

I have the following Python 2.7 code that works perfectly on a Windows 7 machine:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
app = CreateObject('Access.Application')
from comtypes.gen import Access
DBEngine = app.DBEngine
```

On two others (Windows 7 and Windows 10) with MS Access 365 installed (latest version), I get the following error:

```
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147312566, 'Erreur lors du chargement de la biblioth\xe8que/DLL du type.', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

(Meaning "Error loading DLL library)

I assume it's a DLL issue. Reinstalling Office didn't solve it. Has anyone already met that issue? Otherwise, what would be the general method to find the problem/fix it?

Comment: [DBEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821724.aspx) requires the Microsoft Access database engine which some users may have to separately download its [set of components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to that question: the ["click-to-run" version of Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864733.aspx) runs in a virtual environment and the Python libraries may not find it.

The answer to that issue is to uninstall Office and reinstall it as a normal download. After we did that, the program (which had already been tested successfully on another machine) started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `win32com.client` for that? `comtypes` is not so stable and is useful for custom COM interfaces (where other approach is impossible). All MS Office products have nice and standard **IDispatch** COM interface that are reachable by `win32com.client`. Standard PyWin32 docs describe `"Excel.Application"` example, but it can be easily applied for MS Access as well.

Fortunately there are several examples on StackOverflow:

[Python code for running ms-Access Module Subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32653792/3648361)

[Python Create Access database using win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15656445/3648361)